# variable_get('var') VS $GLOBALS['conf']['var']

Tags: 7, configuration

Let's say I set a variable in settings.php:
`$conf['var'] = foo;`

In my module or theme code, I can access this with either:
`variable_get('var');` or `$GLOBALS['conf']['var'];`

Which is the preferred method and why?

Comment: I think this might be opinion base and/or base on the use case. IMO, I will use `variable_get('var');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pros:

- [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)() provides the ability to give you a fallback if it
  doesn't exist
- using the variable directly could wind up with a PHP
  notice if it doesn't exist is able to use the variable system (and
  any available hooks)

  - accesses all the variables ([settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21default%21default.settings.php/7), variables in the DB, etc.) - a one stop shop. I don't believe $conf does this. A simple print_r($GLOBALS['conf']) would show if that is true or not

Cons:

- accessing the variable directly is more efficient since it doesn't execute any functions or require any logic

Personally I would use [variable_get](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7)() because of the fallback functionality and ability to tap into whatever other sources the variable system may provide

Comment: `variable_get()` is just a thin wrapper around `$conf`, and doesn't touch the DB or settings.php directly.  Part of bootstrap is to load all variables from cache/database and merge them with any `$conf` from settings.php.  Start reading from `_drupal_bootstrap_variables()` and then `variable_initialize()` to see how this works.

Comment: Wow. You are correct. I guess I valued the fallback so much I assumed it did more. Every time I worked with `$conf` it was way too early in the process before it merged variables.

Answer (score 7):

It is preferable to use [`variable_get()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7) instead of `$GLOBALS['conf']['var']`.

Despite being gone in Drupal 8, you always want to ***program to the API*** instead of ***programming to the implementation***.

It is highly unlikely, but there could be some change that pops up in Drupal 7 where there is a difference between the two.  For example, a future version could include a `hook_variable_alter()` to allow modules to muck with variables between the database and their usage.